# how can i install all node modules in different folders?

Tags: node.js

How can I install required dependencies in multiple folders at once? I have several assignments in one folder and don't want to have to go into each one to individually to run npm install. (you have to wait for each one before you can move on, ect ect) I'd like to be able to run one command in terminal to progress through each folder and all the dependencies in each of the package.json files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me understand, you have multiple folders with `package.json` files and you want to install the dependencies in all folders with only one command, right?

If your answer is affirmative and you're under linux or osx, you can use the find command.

```
find . -name 'package.json' -not -path '*/node_modules*' -execdir npm install \;
```

This command will find every `package.json` file excluding every `node_modules` folder and will run the command `npm install`.

Comment: that is exactly what i wanted and it worked perfectly!